# Android tab activity

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

hi all
i have a tab activity in which there four tabs 
now this activity can be started by three other activities
based on the activity that started the current tab has to be set in the tab activity
i tried using extras  specifying which should be the current tab in the intent that started the tabactivity
but it dont seem to realize the extras at all

Comment: Have you written the code in the tab activity to select the correct tab for the information specified in the intent extras?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the code that starts the Intent (three other activities) and the code that reads the extras (the tab activity).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using

`myTabHost.setCurrentTab(2);`

method. So just pass the tab id you want to display first with intent. Use it in your myTabActivity.java to display the tab you want.